# Installing javac for fedora 20 and java version 1.6

Tags: java, fedora

By default, I had Java 7 installed on my system(X64, Fedora 20).

I needed Java 6 for a software, hence had to remove 7.

```
sudo yum remove *java*
```

And then, I installed Java 6.

This installs Java 6 successfully. but the java compiler, JavaC is missing. 
For that, I try -

```
su -c "yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel"

Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No package java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Could someone please help me with installing javac for java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove javac by `yum remove *javac*`. `javac` is a binary and not a package. You also can't install `OpenJDK 6` from official Fedora repositories because it is no longer available.

If it is a program that you want to run on JDK6 you could set `compiler compliance level` to 1.6 and it should work.

The easiest possible option would be to install Oracle JDK 6. You can install it along with your existing installation of any other Java using `alternatives`.

You can very easily adopt this [guide](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-6-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) to install Oracle JDK 6 on your Fedora 20.

Comment: Edited, the question. Could I have Sun Java instead, it tastes better.

Comment: You can very easily use the guide I linked in the post to install JDK 6 on your Fedora box.